# Como pegar os filhos de um elemento com JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dom

Possuo uma `<div>` com diversos filhos, como mostrada a seguir:

```
<div id="minha-div>
    <span class="filhos-1" id="filho-1"><!-- outros aqui --></span>
    <p class="filhos-2" id="filho-2"><!-- outros aqui --></p>
    <div class="filhos-1" id="filho-3">
        <span class="filhos-2" id="filho-4"><!-- outros aqui --></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

E eu quero realizar operações com os elementos filhos da `<div>`, de forma semelhante ao pseudocódigo abaixo:

```
var pai = document.getElementById("minha-div");

// retorna os elementos #filho-1 e #filho-3
var filhos1 = pai.pesquisa('.filhos-1');

// retorna os elementos #filho-2 e #filho-4
var filhos2 = pai.pesquisa('.filhos-2');
```

Como devo proceder para realizar essas seleções sem usar `JQuery`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eu te aconselho a fazer as suas buscas utilizando `document.querySelector` ou `document.querySelectorAll`, com eles você é capaz de fazer buscas utilizando a sintaxe de CSS.

```
<div id="minha-div>
    <span class="filhos-1" id="filho-1"><!-- outros aqui --></span>
    <p class="filhos-2" id="filho-2"><!-- outros aqui --></p>
    <div class="filhos-1" id="filho-3">
        <span class="filhos-2" id="filho-4"><!-- outros aqui --></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Nesse seu exemplo você poderia buscar todos os elementos filhos apenas de minha div utilizando `document.querySelectorAll('#minha-div > *')` ou buscar todos os elementos abaixo de `#minha-div` que tenham a classe `filhos-1` utilizando `document.querySelectorAll('#minha-div .filhos-1')` e assim por diante.

```js
console.log('#minha-div > *');
let filhos = document.querySelectorAll('#minha-div > *');
filhos.forEach(console.log);
console.log('');

console.log('#minha-div .filhos-1');
filhos = document.querySelectorAll('#minha-div .filhos-1');
filhos.forEach(console.log);
console.log('');
```

```html
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div id="minha-div">
    <span class="filhos-1" id="filho-1"><!-- outros aqui --></span>
    <p class="filhos-2" id="filho-2"><!-- outros aqui --></p>
    <div class="filhos-1" id="filho-3">
        <span class="filhos-2" id="filho-4"><!-- outros aqui --></span>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Caso você tenha duvidas sobre como construir essas buscas, aqui estão são duas referencias sobre Seletores em CSS:
https://tableless.com.br/referencia-seletores-css/
https://www.maujor.com/tutorial/guia-completo-seletores-css3.php

Answer (score 4):

Se quiser algum elemento, basta fazer igual ao ao que você fez para pegar o pai:

```js
var pai = document.getElementById("minha-div");

var filho1 = document.getElementById("filho-1") // Aqui
console.log(filho1);
```

```html
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div id="minha-div">
    <span class="filhos-1" id="filho-1"><!-- outros aqui --></span>
    <p class="filhos-2" id="filho-2"><!-- outros aqui --></p>
    <div class="filhos-1" id="filho-3">
        <span class="filhos-2" id="filho-4"><!-- outros aqui --></span>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Agora, se quiser pegar todos filhos do `pai` de uma vez, basta usar o `children`:

```js
var pai = document.getElementById("minha-div");

var filhos = pai.children; // Aqui
console.log(filhos);
```

```html
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div id="minha-div">
    <span class="filhos-1" id="filho-1"><!-- outros aqui --></span>
    <p class="filhos-2" id="filho-2"><!-- outros aqui --></p>
    <div class="filhos-1" id="filho-3">
        <span class="filhos-2" id="filho-4"><!-- outros aqui --></span>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```